# POST JSON from Javascript client to Jersey resource in Atmosphere framework

Tags: java, javascript, json, jersey, atmosphere

I have been Googling and trying to get this to work for hours...The problem is the server is not receiving data as `JSON` but as text. This is the POJO

```
package my.package;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

    @XmlRootElement
    public class TestConfig {

        private String firmID;
        private String traderID;
        private String userID;

        public TestConfig() {};
    ...
    }
```

A Javascript client which contains:

```
    function callbackForTest(response) {
        console.log("Call to callbackForTest");
        if (response.state == "opening" && response.status == 200) {

            //push request data
            if (connectedEndpoint[0] == null) {
                console.log("[DEBUG] Connected endpoint for " + value + "is null!");
                //disable button
                $(value).attr('disabled','');
                $.atmosphere.unsubscribe();
                return false;
            }

            // push ( POST ) 
            connectedEndpoint[0].push(JSON.stringify(
                    {
                        operation       :   "RUN",
                        firmID          :   $('#firmID').val(),
                        userID          :   $('#userID').val(),
                        traderID        :   $('#traderID').val(),
                        protocol        :   $('#protocol').val(),
                        group1          :   
                    }
                ));
        }
    }

    function subscribeUrl(jobName, call, transport) {
        var location = subscribePath + jobName.id;
        return subscribeAtmosphere(location, call, transport);
    }

    function globalCallback(response) {
        if (response.state != "messageReceived") {
            return;
        }
    }

    function subscribeAtmosphere(location, call, transport) {
        var rq = $.atmosphere.subscribe(location, globalCallback, $.atmosphere.request = {
            logLevel : 'debug',
            transport : transport,
            enableProtocol: true,
            callback : call,
            contentType : 'application/json'
        });
        return rq;
    }

    function sendMessage(connectedEndpoint, jobName) {
        var phrase = $('#msg-' + jobName).val();
        connectedEndpoint.push({data: "message=" + phrase});
    }


    // Run Test handlers
    $("input[name='runButtons']").each(function(index, value){
        $(value).click(function(){

            //disable button
            $(value).attr('disabled','disabled');

            // connect (GET)
            connectedEndpoint[index] = subscribeUrl(value, callbackForTest, transport);
            });
        });
```

I have included the libs shown in this screenshot:

[LIBS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJj5O.png)

And this is my web.xml (part of it)

com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature
           true

The Jersey resource

```
@Path("/subscribe/{topic}")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, "text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN})
public class Subscriber {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(Subscriber.class);

    @PathParam("topic")
    private Broadcaster topic;

    @GET
    public SuspendResponse<String> subscribe() {
        LOG.debug("GET - OnSubscribe to topic");
        SuspendResponse<String> sr = new SuspendResponse.SuspendResponseBuilder<String>().broadcaster(topic).outputComments(true)
                .addListener(new EventsLogger()).build();

        return sr;
    }

    @POST
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN, MediaType.TEXT_HTML})
    @Broadcast
    public Broadcastable publish( TestConfig t) {
        LOG.debug("POST");
        String s = t.getFirmID();
        return new Broadcastable(s, "", topic);
    }
```

I can subscribe OK. When I try to push to the server, I get this exception:

```
A message body reader for Java class com.mx.sailcertifier.TestConfig, and Java type class com.mx.sailcertifier.TestConfig, and MIME media type text/plain was not found.
```

Why is it sending plain text if I set the content type to `application/json`? What is the correct way to get the Jersey resource to read the JSON?

Comment: It looks like your client is POSTing the TestConfig object as JSON, but with a Content-Type of "text/plain." If you use Firebug or something similar to monitor the actual POST to /subscribe/{topic}, 1) what value do you see for the request header Content-Type and 2) what does the actual request body look like?

Comment: I am subscribing to Atmosphere using `var contentType = 'application/json'` (see `subscribeAtmosphere` in Javascript code block). Is there some other way I should be passing the JSON object?

Comment: Oh, yes, I see it now. Still, what do you *actually* see for the POST request headers and body in Firebug, Fiddler, the Chrome Developer Tools or your debugger of choice? Knowing that would allow us to at least narrow down the problem to client vs. server.

Comment: Sorry, yes...I checked that too, in Chrome debugger and Firebug. I don't actually SEE the `POST` under the Network tab. Just the `GET` which occurs when `subscribe` is called. Normally, there should be a `POST` when `push` is called, but it's not happening in the debugger trace. It's as if the failure to create the TestConfig object in the Jersey resource (`publish(TestConfig t`) blocks the POST from completing. Or something like that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got this working with two changes:

After looking at the sample [here](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/tree/master/samples/rest-chat), I added this `init-param` to the `AtmosphereServlet` in the `web.xml` to resolve the `text/plain` problem in Tomcat:

```
<init-param>
     <param-name>org.atmosphere.websocket.messageContentType</param-name>
     <param-value>application/json</param-value>
</init-param>
```

I didn't see this anywhere documented in the Atmosphere docs. It would have saved a lot of time had it been, but documentation-wise the API is unfortunately disorganized and lacking.

Also, I needed to use the [jersey-bundle](http://maven.java.net/service/local/artifact/maven/redirect?r=releases&g=com.sun.jersey&a=jersey-bundle&v=1.17&e=jar) jar make sure that everything Jersey related is included, including as the `jersey-json.jar`. After that, it worked! Hope this helps someone else who may have been stuck with the same or similar problem.